# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'

Tags: php, pdo, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-14.04

I am using php 7.4 and ubuntu 16.04 which I have upgraded from 14.04.

Here I am randomly getting pdo error like:

```
PHP Core Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params))'

in Unknown:0

Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() #1 {main}
```

**Also, the same issue on my other AWS instance which is running on ubuntu 14.04**

Comment: The error is quite obvious, you need to install a php module `pdo_mysql`

Comment: it's already installed and as I mentioned it throws error randomly and not every time